# We found a problem with some content in 'FileName.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?

Tags: excel, ag-grid

I have used ag-grid master-details data rendering, and using export functionality. After downloading excel file, when I try to open file, its giving warning, "**We found a problem with some content in 'FileName.xlsx'.Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, Click Yes**". On window OS, file get recovered but on Mac, file is not getting recovered.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a good idea to take over control of the export functionality by handling the export on the back-end. There are libraries for most languages for writing Excel files.